# How do I mount Samba share as non-root user

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

Is there a step-by-step tutorial that instructs in detail how to smbmount a Samba share to be used by a **non-root** user on a Ubuntu 10.04 desktop?

Note: there are numerous threads on Google search dealing with this seemingly new problem. Instructions that used to work on Ubuntu 8.04 (or an older version of smbfs) no longer work.

I need to find something that's up to date and reproducible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A very nice tool to easily mount your samba shares in your home folder is [SMBNetFS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/smbnetfs). With this tool you can access your samba shares by nearly all applications simply through a mount point in your home.

#### How to use SMBnetFS:

- Install the package through your package manager
- `cp /etc/smbnetfs.conf ~/.smb/smbnetfs.conf` copy standard configuration
- `cp /etc/samba/smb.conf ~/.smb/smb.conf` copy samba configuration
- `mkdir ~/sambashare` or any other name for the mount point
- `smbnetfs ~/sambashare` mount the shares to the mountpoint

Unfortunately there is only little documentation available. See `man smbnetfs` for options and go through the FAQ file in `/usr/share/doc/smbnetfs`.

Comment: +1 for the detailed steps. I hope this works with Eclipse, because with gvfs Eclipse definitely doesn't work. Do you happen to know how SMBnetFS is different from smbfs?

Comment: SMBNetFS uses fuse. Make sure users are in the `fuse` group.

Comment: +1 again! Doesn't gfvs use FUSE as well? How is it different from what I already have prepackaged (gvfs) with my GNOME desktop?

Answer (score 9):

When using gnome, you can simply type in the smb:// url into Nautilus. Normally gvfs-fuse and other gvfs packages should be installed, so that you can mount samba directly with the file browser. Additionally you should find all mounted stuff in your ~/.gvfs folder. This even works with other protocols and compressed files etc.

```
gvfs-mount smb://user@server/storage
```

I've tested it with eclipse and other tools and it works. gvfs-fuse must be installed.

Comment: Thanks but Eclipse won't work with this. I tried this already, that's why I was specifically asking about smbmount (a symbolic link to mount.cifs which is part of the smbfs package).

Comment: So eclipse can't access .gvfs in your home dir? As far as I know, every program should be able to do this. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Nowadays it's `gio mount` instead of `gvfs-mount`. See `man gio` or [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio.html) for details.

Answer (score 6):

## In 2022

### For scripting

If you need to mount a remote smb share locally, you can use the `gio` toolkit. It isn't handy if you want to view the remote share in a file manager, but it's very useful in scripting.

```bash
gio mount --anonymous "smb://servername/share"
gio copy --progress "smb://servername/share/filename.ext" /local/folder/
gio mount --unmount "smb://servername/share"
```

`gio` does not require superuser privileges, reads quoted strings with spaces normally, and works with Cyrillic characters.

In Ubuntu 22.04 `gio` is installed by default.

### ...But if you need to work with files in the file manager, especially in `Dolphin`

In this case you can use `smb4k`.

```
sudo apt install smb4k
```

This program connects to `smb://` shares anonymously or with credentials, can mount shares at startup, has profiles and a lot of settings. But most importantly, it allows you to work with files in `Dolphin` directly, without caching it, as if they were stored locally. So you can use, for example, `kid3` to edit remote files.

Answer (score 2):

`man mount` will help you determine what options you want.  If the windows system will always be available. You can just add the mount to the `/etc/fstab` and it will be mounted.  You can allow the user to mount and unmount the partition as required using the options `user,noauto`.  To allow others to unmount it change `user` to `users`.

Autofs also supports on demand mounts using samba.  The incantation depends on which directories you want mounted when.  I've run it successfully in a development environment.

EDIT:  If you need to do this for a lot of users, I suggest using autofs to do the mounting.  This does not require changes to fstab.  Obtaining credentials for the various users may be a problem.  I use a directory structure in the form `/net/$HOST/$USER` for my mounts.  Autofs is configured for the `/net/$HOST` portion of the mount and automatically mounts the directories under it as needed.

Particular mounting approaches depend on your needs.  I have had cases where users needed their Desktop directory mounted on the server, although typical mounts are server based.

For large organization with lots of user it may make sense to move the directories to a Linux server and use Samba to share the files to Windows users.  I haven't tried the reverse, but it may be possible.

Comment: This works, but you need root access to change fstab. Even if are root, note that it is quite impractical if you have to do it for a lot of users, each with a specific share to mount (as in a large organization where each user has a personal share in a centralized file server).

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while researching the magic I performed recently to do exactly this for one of my users. My workflow differs remarkably to the other answers. Do note, however, this is about the most simple case possible.

Assuming your username is `ae` and your home is `/home/ae`

1) Set up smbfs:
`mkdir /home/ae/.smb`

1a) If windows login credentials are needed, create and edit the file: `/home/ae/.smb/smbnetfs.conf` to have contents:

```
auth winuser "winpassword"
```

`winuser` is the user created on the Windows computer you wish to access. `winpassword` is that user's password to log in to Windows on that computer.

2) Create your mount point:
`mkdir /home/ae/nethood`

3) Execute the smbnetfs command:
`smbnetfs /home/ae/nethood`

---

Note the entire "network neighborhood" will show up under `/home/ae/nethood` with the workgroups being the first layer of subdirectories.

All of the listings below were copied from my browsing of folders as a non privileged user on an ubuntu host. Username and group changed to `ae`. `sudo` was never used. The Windows computers are on informal Windows network and shared folders are user/password protected (on the Windows computer using the windows username and password).

```
$ cd nethood
$ ls -alh
total 12K
drwxrwxrwx 9 ae   ae     0 Dec 31  1969 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 ae   ae    21 Jul 28 11:49 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 Dec 31  1969 WORKGROUP
```

Browse the workgroup `WORKGROUP`:

```
$ cd WORKGROUP
$ ls -alh
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  0 Dec 31  1969 .
drwxrwxrwx 9 root root  0 Dec 31  1969 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Dec 31  1969 HTPC -> ../HTPC
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Dec 31  1969 NEWPC -> ../NEWPC
```

Change directory to computers and any shared folders will be listed and accessed as normal.

```
$ cd NEWPC
$ ls -alh
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Dec 31  1969 .
drwxrwxrwx 9 root root 0 Dec 31  1969 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Dec 31  1969 Desktop
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Dec 31  1969 Users
```

And the files:

```
$ cd Desktop/
$ ls -alh
ls: cannot access desktop.ini: No such file or directory
total 30M
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     0 Dec 31  1969 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     0 Dec 31  1969 ..
-rwxr--r-- 1 ae   ae    1.5K Jan 25  2013 Command Prompt.lnk
-????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? desktop.ini
-rwxr--r-- 1 ae   ae    156K May 28  2013 Download %25285%2529.iif
-rwxr--r-- 1 ae   ae    2.4K Jul 24 12:28 Google Chrome.lnk
-rwxr--r-- 1 ae   ae     178 Feb  4  2013 import orders.bat
-rwxr--r-- 1 ae   ae    2.3M Mar 30  2012 msvc2008_x86_vcredist_x64.exe
drwxr-xr-x 2 ae   ae       0 May 20  2014 OpenOffice 4.1.0 (en-US) Installation Files
-rwxr--r-- 1 ae   ae    406K Jun  6  2013 Paypal_Jan_1_2012_to_Dec_31_2012.iif
-rwxr--r-- 1 ae   ae     15M May  8  2012 php-5.4.3-Win32-VC9-x86.zip
-rwxr--r-- 1 ae   ae    1.9K Jul 24 13:03 PSPad.lnk
-rwxr--r-- 1 ae   ae    1.1K Jul 24 12:31 VB Demo.lnk
```

Notice the above directories have ownership `root root`. File ownership will be the same as your user.

No other users will be able to access the folders regardless of the mount point or that folder's ownership or permissions. If your user can "write" to that folder (and it is empty), smbnetfs will mount the network neighborhood there and not allow anyone else access, even `root`. For `root` to have access, you must `su ae`.

---

If there are no shared folders, the computer's directory will be empty.

If you do not have credentials to the Windows computer, you may get the error:
`ls: cannot open directory .: Input/output error`

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu I used the package cifs-utils per this article: [How to Mount Samba share in Ubuntu Linux](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/mount-samba-share-ubuntu-cifs/).

I wanted a mount point under my home directory. It's for non-media files. I created an entry in /etc/fstab. It was owned by root, though, and I couldn't edit in that location.

The answer was in the man page for mount.cifs. I added to fstab the option uid=MyUserName. My user name on the cifs client is the same as on the cifs host. I don't know if that is a requirement, but it worked.