# Add files from a network location in VLC

Tags: 11.04, vlc

I'm trying to add several video files to my playlist in VLC Media Player. These files are located in a network location and the "Add Files" option displays only local file locations. I tried using the IP address of device but that does nothing. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least three options:

1. Browse to `~/.gvfs`

   Your network drive is mounted in your home directory in the hidden directory `~/.gvfs`. You can browse there with the file browser from VLC or enter the appropriate path in the *Add Files* dialogue.
2. [**smbnetfs**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/smbnetfs) [image: Install smbnetfs]

   Will help you to mount your network directory to your home. By this any application will be able to access it (see also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24348/how-do-i-mount-samba-share-as-non-root-user/24376#24376)).
3. [**ushare**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ushare) [image: Install ushare].

   Installs an UPnP server on the media server. VLC and other players are able to read files from there (the GUI [stream2ip](https://launchpad.net/stream2ip) helps you to set it up)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Advanced Open" instead of "Add file". This displays the full VLC open dialog--complete with a "Network" tab, rather than the system "File Open" dialog. Of course, you have to remember to "Enqueue" the file(s), rather than Play.