# how do you mount network drives?

Tags: networking, share

When I access a network folder using nautilus it shows up in the Places sidebar, but not in any other application's save/open Places sidebar. Why the inconsistency, and how can I add a share so every application has access to it without having to edit fstab?

Comment: The only way I have found to do this myself is to in fact, edit fstab.  But once you are willing to do that it works brilliantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default network shares are mounted in the hidden directory `~/.gvfs` in our home directory. You can browse there with any application provided you have enabled to display hidden folders.

[smbnetfs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/smbnetfs)[image: Install smbnetfs]

With this tool we are also able to mount network shares as a non-root user in any newly created folder in our home directories. For a short explanation on how to use it see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24348/how-do-i-mount-samba-share-as-non-root-user/24376#24376).

Comment: Hmm, I can see the network shares but usb-creator-gtk fails when I try to use an .iso from there. I wish there was more network transparency in ubuntu. I feel that ubuntu isn't ready to be used in a network yet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount network disk through terminal by command:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=myusername,password=mysharepassword //myipaddress/mysharefolder /myPCdirfolder
```

Make sure package `cifs-utils` is installed. After logout network disk will be dismounted.