# is there any way to mount cifs partitions with only user permissions

Tags: cifs

I am trying to mount cifs/samba drives on an Ubuntu machine.  It seems as though I either need to run it under root or modify my fstab, which also requires root permissions.

On Mac, mount_smbfs does not require root.

Is there any way for a normal user to mount without requiring root to either modify the fstab OR running it in Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: You may also try with [SMBNetFS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24348/how-do-i-mount-samba-share-as-non-root-user/24376#24376)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mount requires root. Always.

However on desktop machines, it is common to circumvent this. Ubuntu Desktop (with Gnome GUI) allows local users to mount smbfs/cifs network shares via `Places -> Connect to Server -> Windows shares`.

There are other options to allow user mounts. To enable them, you will need support from root.

Comment: Does the circumvention require a one time root access?

Comment: @engineerchuan Yes. (However, on a standard desktop install, the circumvention is the default behaviour.)