# Cannot mount Windows 98 SE share over SSH to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows, mount, users, sharing, cifs

I am in a SSH session to Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to mount a Windows 98SE share using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/uniserv /tmp/uniserv/ -o sec=lanman,servern=Uniplus1
```

In response Ubuntu asks me for a root password for the share:

```
Password for root@//192.168.0.2/uniserv:
```

Why is the share not mounting and why am I being asked for a root password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the `mount` command as root and haven't specified a different username. You can add `username=user` to the `-o` list (where ***`user`*** is the username on target machine):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/uniserv /tmp/uniserv/ -o username=user,sec=lanman,servern=Uniplus1
```

If you want to *connect to the share as a guest*, use `guest` instead of `username=user` in the `-o` list:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/uniserv /tmp/uniserv/ -o guest,sec=lanman,servern=Uniplus1
```

If the server gives information about ownership and permissions, `mount.cifs` will try to respect it. Otherwise, all files and directories in the share will be owned by root, and accessible only by root. If you don't want that, you can add use the `uid` and or `gid` arguments to specify user or group IDs. A common way is `uid=$UID`. For example:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/uniserv /tmp/uniserv/ -o guest,uid=$UID,sec=lanman,servern=Uniplus1
```

The [`UID` environment variable](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables) is a [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/bash.1.html)ism (also in [`zsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/zsh.1.html)), so if you're invoking this command from a shell that doesn't support it (such as [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/dash.1.html), which [provides `sh` in Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)), use [`$(id -ru)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/id.1.html) instead (or manually put in your actual [user ID number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) from [`/etc/passwd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//etc/passwd#Password_file)):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/uniserv /tmp/uniserv/ -o guest,uid=$(id -ru),sec=lanman,servern=Uniplus1
```

***Source:*** Mainly [`man mount.cifs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/mount.cifs.8.html).

If you'd prefer to perform the mount operation itself as a regular (non-root) user, [How do I mount Samba share as non-root user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24348/how-do-i-mount-samba-share-as-non-root-user) may help.

Comment: @Hendre Which command is giving that?

Comment: here is the complete command I am using: 

`sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/uniserv /mnt/uniplus/ -o credentials=/etc/rivsen/.uniplus1.credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,sec=lanman,workgroup=SENTRA,servern=Uniplus1`

1. I can ping the host, however the command waits for a response indefinitely? 

2. `sudo smbtree` lists the host but not the uniserv share.

3. I can access the share from Nautilus

Answer (score 0):

I solved an issue how to connect old Windows 98 to Ubuntu/Debian using mount.cifs (in my case my system is `Raspbian`), working command is:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=guest,pass=,vers=1.0,sec=none,domain=MOSSBAUERLAB,ip=192.168.10.217,servern=MICHAEL //MICHAEL/AUTOSAVES /mnt/sm2201/dev
```

Where:

- `MICHAEL` is my computer name
- `AUTOSAVES` name of shared folder
- `MOSSBAERLAB` is a Workgroup name

There are one significant thing that should be Noted, all names (Computer, Workgroup, Share) must be in uppercase.