# Mount SMB share with gvfs from command line

Tags: samba, cifs, gvfs, smb

There are many ways to mount an SMB share in Ubuntu. For example:

- as root, you can use mount.cifs:

  ```
  mount -t cifs -o user=username //servername/sharename/ /mnt
  ```
- you can use smbnetfs as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24348/how-do-i-mount-samba-share-as-non-root-user)

However, I would like to use gvfs. When logging in using ssh. I tried the following without a success:

```
dbus-launch bash
gvfs-mount smb://servername/sharename/
```

This works... kind of. When I run

```
gvfs-mount -l
```

I get the following:

```
Mount(0): sharename on servername -> smb://servername/sharename/
  Type: GDaemonMount
```

So, the mount seems to work. However, there is no file system mount point, whereas when I mount it using Nautilus, I get a mountpoint in `/run/user/1000/gvfs/`, which I can then access using command line.

What should I do to get a mount point with gvfs which I can access with the command line?

Answer (score 8):

At least with Ubuntu 18.04, the following works:

```
$ gio mount smb://<server>/<share>
Password required for share <share> on <server>
User [<user>]:
Domain [<workgroup>]:
Password:
```

The mount points are located in `/run/user/<uid>/gvfs/` ([idem](https://askubuntu.com/a/33513/349837) `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs`).

Comment: For unattended mount with username/password/workgroup try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027175/349837). Then you can create a symlink to whatever with eg `ln -si $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs/mysmbmount $HOME/smb`

Comment: For me, this only works when issued from a terminal window in a gnome session. If I ssh in (like in the question) and run the same command I get: `gio: smb://<server>/<share>: volume doesn't implement mount.`

Answer (score 3):

The mount point should be in `~/.gvfs`. At least by me it was there with this name: `smb-share\:domain\=WORKGROUP\,server\=192.168.0.186\,share\=asmedia-hdd\,user\=root/`. If you still cannot find it, you can try `sudo find / -name sharename -type d`. Maybe it finds the directory somewhere else. Another possible location is `/run/user/1000/gvfs`.