# gio mount password with special characters

Tags: mount, samba, password

I want mount using well-known way

```
gio mount smb://<user>:<password>@<server>/<share>/
```

In my case

```
gio mount "smb://WORKGROUP;myuser:+B@e}F)q8tra@@192.168.1.199/"
```

I get warning
Authentication Required
Enter password for “192.168.1.199”:

It is because of my password `+B@e}F)q8tra@` I try convert it using [this converter](https://www.urlencoder.org/) to `%2BB%40e%7DF%29q8tra%40` but without success... I try add symbol `\` with different combinations without success.

I read [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021643/how-to-specify-a-password-when-mounting-a-smb-share-with-gio/1027175#1027175). I only found dirty hack [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021643/how-to-specify-a-password-when-mounting-a-smb-share-with-gio)

```
echo "+B@e}F)q8tra@" | gio mount "smb://WORKGROUP;myuser@192.168.1.199/"
```

With this hack works.

Ho do without hack?