# Drag and drop files from file explorer in sftp folder onto vscode

Tags: files, sftp

I browse files through `sftp` on the file explorer, aka `Files`. I would like to drag and drop them, or double click them to open them on my local programs, such as `vscode` or `paraview` for instance. Here is my current behaviour:

- Double clicking opens an empty window.
- Drag and drop, if anything, pastes the path to the file (including the sftp command).

I am running 64 bit `Ubuntu 22.04.4` with `GNOME 42.9`.

Comment: Do the files appear under `/run/user/1000/.gvfs/`? https://askubuntu.com/a/1159685/1004020

Comment: No, they don't. The path is like: sftp://user@domain/<file>